# How to disable pdf file download option using JQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, pdf

How to disable pdf download using jquery or javascript.

In my website I am loading some pdf files in iframe. I need to protect my files. 
So how can I dissable pdf file download, print those kind of options.
Please help me.

My website created using html. jquery, mysql and php

Comment: Doesn't sound possible. refer to http://forums.adobe.com/thread/466540

Comment: You have to develop something like http://www.scribd.com/

Comment: possible duplicate of [Prevent PDF file from downloading and printing](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4930914/prevent-pdf-file-from-downloading-and-printing)

Comment: @Juhana, Actually he wanted a javascript/jQuery solution...

Comment: Though not possible with js/jQuery you can try your hand on http://code.google.com/p/purepdf/ its a flash solution. not sure if it will work..

Comment: @Imdad The answer is still the same: not possible.

Comment: @Juhana, same answer doen't makes a question duplicate

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are delivering pdf file directly into the browser, displayed using Adobe Reader ActiveX, how can it be possible to prevent file download, since the files are displayed after downloaded into your temp directory?

So it is not possible using ANY JavaScript library.

The only way to secure your master PDF files is by creating Images for each page and present those to the user on the web via your own interface (html, flash etc).

You may use **[ImageMagick](http://www.imagemagick.org/)** along with **[GhostScript](http://sourceforge.net/projects/ghostscript/)** for this.

You may go through [www.veryinteractivepeople.com/?p=521](http://www.veryinteractivepeople.com/?p=521)

Hope this helps...`:)`