# Prevent right click on <iframe> where an iframe contains PDF file in Internet Explorer(IE strictly)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Prevent PDF file from downloading and printing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4930914/prevent-pdf-file-from-downloading-and-printing)

I kow we have lots of post to prevent right click on ,

here i'm trying to have an  containing PDF where user cannot right click on the pdf for Internet Explorer browser.

The basic idea is to prevent user from copying or printing the pdf file.

I have done following code it works on chrome, but fails badly on IE. 
FYI - PDF file is on same Domain

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Disable Context Menu</title>
<script type="text/jscript">
  function disableContextMenu()
  {
    window.frames["fraDisabled"].document.oncontextmenu = function(){alert("Right Click disabled!"); return false;};   
    // Or use this
    // document.getElementById("fraDisabled").contentWindow.document.oncontextmenu = function(){alert("Right Click disabled!"); return false;};;    
  }  
</script>
</head>
<body bgcolor="#FFFFFF" onload="disableContextMenu();" oncontextmenu="return false">
<iframe id="fraDisabled" width="528" height="473" src="landscape.pdf#toolbar=0&navpanes=0" onload="disableContextMenu();" onMyLoad="disableContextMenu();"></iframe>
</body>
</html>
```

Or is there any other to protect your pdf file working on IE ?

Comment: There is no way to protect viewable files on the internet - if you can see it, you can copy it. Screenshot? Turn off scripts?... there are many ways. No matter what you try, a reasonably equipped user could spend less time making a duplicate.

Answer (score 6):

One way you can do it is to unbind all the mouse events. Would't be the best way. And I agree with ahren

```
<iframe id="fraDisabled" style="pointer-events:none;" src="landscape.pdf#toolbar=0&navpanes=0"/>
```

Comment: It doesn't prevent right click on IE <iframe> containing PDF file.

Answer (score 1):

You could always use something like http://pageflip.hu/ and create the file into a SWF or onto a video to deter people from copying it easily, but as "ahren" said if you can see it you can copy it.