# I don't want visiters of my laravel app to copy nor download pdf files that i allow them to see

Tags: laravel, laravel-4, laravel-5, laravel-5.3

I want visitors to be able to view a part of some pdfs on my laravel project, but i don't want them to be able to copy or download the content of them.

For example, on LinkedIn you can actually watch some content of pdf or powerpoint files i think, but you can not copy that content nor download it.

is there any plugin which does that, or some javascript codes to perform that?

Comment: Check this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14664923/how-to-restrict-user-from-downloading-or-saving-pdf-file

Comment: thanks @Jackowski for the link, but it just gives me issues about my question... but in practice i still have no at my question.
In fact, i just want visitors to view pdfs within my Laravel app frame, but i still don't want them to copy the content nor download it.

Could u please help me more my dear?

Comment: or just do as GoogleBooks does, so you can just watch parts of a Book online but you can't download nor copy the content...

Comment: You can't prevent the user to take screenshots.

Comment: your are absolutely right! but i wish to give work before they can actually arrive to that point :)

Comment: Read the link above and this one to take some possibilities: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4930914/prevent-pdf-file-from-downloading-and-printing

Comment: Is this not futile? How you going to stop screenshots?