# Laravel: Giving url of securely stored files on storage/app to jquery library

Tags: php, jquery, laravel

I have stored my PDF files using the storage API. To let the browser read PDF I could use the Response::make() but I am using the pdfObject jquery library to display it embedded. And the problem is while using the library, I have to provide the url of pdf:

```
var pdf = new PDFObject({
   url: **"THE URL TO THE PDF",**
   pdfOpenParams: {
   navpanes: 0,
   toolbar: 0,
   statusbar: 0,
   view: "FitV"
}
```

How can I give the URL of the securely stored PDF to the library?
Any help appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can make a new "loader" controller, from which you can return a pdf header with the desired file. Then instead of calling the file directly, pass its encrypted name as a parameter to the controller and decode it inside:

```
var pdf = new PDFObject({
    url: "site.com/controller/method/<?php Crypt::encrypt('filename.pdf') ?>",
    //...
}
```

Controller:

```
Route::get('/controller/method/{filename}', function($filename) {
    // Laravel is ignoring the header method and is sending a plain html/txt :(
    // So a normal php header can do the workaround
    header("Content-type: application/pdf");

    $filename = '/url/to/pdf/' . Crypt::decrypt($filename);

    $response = Response::make(readfile($filename), 200);
    $response->header('Content-Type', 'application/pdf');
    return $response;
});
```

P.S. The Laravel code is not tested and will mostly likely not work (I am little rusty with it), I tested with pure PHP though, and it worked.

Comment: Thanks! I will try it.. but couldn't users download the pdf if they go to the encrypted url? I don't want them to download the pdf.

Comment: @user1814210 They wouldn't know the directory with this approach, but you can use an htaccess file to prevent the directory from listing.

Comment: I mean when they copy & paste the url `"site.com/controller/method/<?php Crypt::encrypt('filename.pdf') ?>"` from the source code, they will be able to view and save the pdf. Is there any way to prevent this? Thanks for your consideration dude.

Comment: It's rather impossible, anyone can make a screenshot of their own screen and have a copy of the contents from your PDF file. You may want to check this kind of questions around StackOverflow like this one http://stackoverflow.com/q/4930914/1125161

Comment: @user1814210 I have updated my answer with a working controller example, hope it works for you. I have some issues with the headers, but finally did manage to find a workaround.