# What is the most efficient solution for file transfer from back-end to front end

Tags: mongodb, express, pdf, google-drive-api

I'm building an application that allows users to access various educational pdf files using MERN(mongoDB express react node).I find three ways to transfer these pdfs from back-end to front-end.

1.Save pdf files to mongoDB directly then retrieve and send the files through res.send() method of express.

2.Save pdf to a cloud web service like aws or google (Looking forward to use google drive API).Then download the file to my web server and send it to client using res.send().

3.Save pdf to a cloud web service like aws or google (Looking forward to use google drive API). and then send the link to client so that the client can use the link to view the pdf. Assuming i can prevent him from downloading the pdf.

Solution should be chosen keeping in mind i'will be using cheap or free web hosting service(That probably omits choice no. one).PDFs can be accessed by large no. of students.It won't take long to load pdfs on client side.

Any extra solutions are appreciated.

Comment: For option 3, what do you mean by "prevent from downloading the pdf?" ... if you are viewing the PDF client-side, you have downloaded the PDF already as it would be in all of the above cases.

Comment: As for other comments to this, we use AWS S3 storage for such things. Google Drive (as of yet) does support through the API creating a time-limited link and AWS S3 API does. In Google Drive you would need to add specific user access or as you said, get it to your server (with your access credentials) and then send. In AWS S3 API, you can create a link without changing permissions that would expire in 1 minute. Send that back to client in AJAX, build a link and click it, then remove it. Even if that user tries to capture and share that link with someone else, it would expire in 1 minute.

Comment: In the third option I mean, I am sending a link from the server and the client is downloading the PDF after clicking that link on the browser and I want to prevent him to download it on his computer.

Comment: When you send() pdf result, the client has it downloaded. If you believe that options 1 and 2 do not allow them to store on their computer you are mistaken.

Comment: Yeah right, but in 3rd option i won't right?

Comment: There is no option short of specialized software for clients. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4930914/prevent-pdf-file-from-downloading-and-printing. Whatever method you use does not allow a user to see a PDF and not download it, it already is downloaded.