# how to show a pdf file in html with removed right click save as option?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, css

How to show  file in html page without download and print option?

How to make it possible with something like this:

```
<embed  src="file.pdf#toolbar=0&navpanes=0&scrollbar=0" width="100%" height="100%"  oncontextmenu= "return false;" >
```

Comment: If this is just for a minor UX tweak then it's potentially possible.  If this is some kind of "security" measure to prevent users from keeping a copy of the file then it's not possible at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm pretty sure this is not possible. Even if you hide the context menu, users can still access it by pressing ctrl+shift+rightclick (keys may vary from browser to browser though).

Edit: while it may not be possible to prevent a user from accessing the context menu, there are still some ways to prevent the user from downloading and/or printing the pdf file. You might want to take a look at the answers to this question here: [Prevent PDF file from downloading and printing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4930914/prevent-pdf-file-from-downloading-and-printing)