# JSP- How to hide toolbar in backend when viewing PDF on browser?

Tags: java, jsp

I have a JSP page that displays a PDF document when it is called. Assuming I generate the URL in this format:

```
http://localhost:8080/repository/file/view/viewPDF.jsp?fileID=27455
```

and send it to another user. The user can view the document (id:27455) on his browser with no problem. But let's say I want to hide the PDF toolbar shown so user is not allowed to access that toolbar.

I found that by entering this link:

```
http://localhost:8080/repository/file/view/viewPDF.jsp?fileID=27455#toolbar=0
```

Then this above will hide the toolbar but it's vulnerable since the other user can change it's value to 1 and the toolbar appears. I am thinking if it's possible to hide it internally in back end code instead but couldn't figure out how.

My viewPDF.jsp:

```
<%@page import="java.io.*"%>



<%@include file="../../../WEB-INF/jspf/mcre.jspf" %>



<%



    response.setContentType("application/pdf");
    boolean debug = true;
    try {


        String snodeid = request.getParameter("nodeID");
        long nodeid = Long.parseLong(snodeid);

        Pdfinfo pdf = PPFacade.getPDFInfo(nodeid);
        String pdfpath = pdf.getFfullpath();
        if (debug) {
            System.out.println("=============== PDF STREAM ================");
            System.out.println("pdfpath = "+ pdfpath);
        }

        //int len = (int)new File("D://test.pdf").length();
        int len = (int)new File(pdfpath).length();
        response.setContentLength(len);
        byte[] buf = new byte[len];
        FileInputStream pdfin = new FileInputStream(pdfpath);
        pdfin.read(buf);
        pdfin.close();
        OutputStream pdfout = response.getOutputStream();
        pdfout.write(buf,0,len);
        pdfout.flush();

        if (debug) {
            System.out.println("=============== END PDF STREAM ================");
        }

    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println(e.getMessage());
    }

%>

<head>
    PDF

</head>
```

Of course I know hiding `#toolbar` is not foolproof since any user with such knowledge can easily bypass it.

Comment: Why don't you just always hide the toolbar and either display the pdf in a new tab/window or an iframe? Sharing the link could then be achieved by providing a "share" button that provides the link to the document only.

Comment: The way it works is I generate a normal link in the format as shown above and send it to someone else. That someone is able to enter the URL on browser and view it.Just like that.

Comment: Also,almost forgot because as a user, I need to check if I have "permission" to print and download. If yes, then sending the link should allow toolbar=1,else sending the link should allow toolbar=0. That's my logic. Hope it makes sense.

Comment: If I understand the problem correctly, some users based on some criteria must have access to the toolbar, while others should not. Therefore I would make a check in the backend, if the current user should be able to see the toolbar (e.g. logged in) and then pass this information in the jsp, in the jsp the toolbar is displayed or not based on that information. Performing that check through the url does not seem like a "clean" solution.

Comment: @Dimitris I believe you got it right. I mean it's not a nice solution nor I could think of a better one,because even by hiding the toolbar, I can easily add `toolbar=1` on the url and it will defeat the purpose, am i right?

Comment: Seems like it, the main question is WHEN someone should be able to see the toolbar. If this is clear I expect that it will be easy to solve your problem programmatically in the backend rather than the frontend. Also, if the backend handles it the user cannot do anything to affect it (like it should be).

Comment: Well, I know when someone should be able to see the toolbar. Let's say if I have print permission and download permission and I get the URL and sent it to you, then you should be able to view the document along with the toolbar. That's all. The issue is I don't want you to see the URL that includes the `#toolbar` so I opt to do so in backend but got no idea how.

Comment: Can i do something to `outputstream pdfout` so it hides the toolbar?

Comment: You describe permissions that are not visible in your code. Also, I have never written java within the jsp, I am pretty sure it falls into bad practises. But the way that I would attack the problem would be the following. Go to your controller, call the services that provide the permissions, check if current user has the permissions required for to see the toolbar, add a boolean model attribute for the toolbar.

Comment: Yea but  just assume I know the logic of using `if else` to attack the problem. I am just interested to know about the toolbar settings in the backend. Because when I enter the URL, it basically is calling `viewPDF.jsp` which is shown in my question.

Comment: I'm not sure allowing users to view a pdf but not to download it if they lack permission is done that easily. If you send the PDF data to the browser to be displayed then the user already has access to it and can save the page etc. - so if you want to prevent a download/print if the user lacks permission you need to send something else, e.g. display only single pages and send them as images (more info: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4930914/prevent-pdf-file-from-downloading-and-printing, https://kbdeveloper.qoppa.com/how-can-i-disable-the-download-button-on-the-browser-pdf-viewer/)

Answer (score 0):

As the toolbar is a function of the browser, not the server or the pdf file, there's no way to force it to be shown or not without notifying the browser in some way.

And anyone intercepting the information that goes to the browser can indeed modify that information.

Of course even were you able to prevent that, they could always download the PDF to their file system and open it using any tool that allows reading PDFs, including such tools as they can create themselves.

So no, you can't lock down such things. And why would you even want to?

Closest you could come is embedding the PDF in a div that loads the PDF viewer browser plugin and uses an AJAX request to the server to retrieve the PDF content. But even then someone can intercept the request to the server and replicate that request using say curl and download the stream to a file directly.

Comment: I see. But can I just disable toolbar to 0 all together and check if it's permission is not allowed?

Comment: @Daredevil no, that permission flag would only affect the page you made to display it. It's not going to have any effect on a 3rd party viewer that just sets that flag and intercepts the output.

Comment: You're right, I could easily click the triple dot on chrome and click `more tools` and click save as and it would still defeat the purpose