# adding and displayin E-Books in django

Tags: python, django, e-commerce, django-file-upload

I am working on a project for selling E-Books but I want to know the best way to display E-Books and handling them considering that users can not download or copy E-Books and can just read them
can anyone help me what can I do?

Comment: It's your [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4930914/prevent-pdf-file-from-downloading-and-printing). This type of question has been asked before.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok I understand that you want to create an online Ebook store where you can sell ebooks. What you can do is create a django application for displaying and buying available ebooks then send the customer an system generated user ID & password to their respected contact details. Now create another djanog application hosted on different domain and only accessible from your custom modified browser that you can build with Electron (https://github.com/electron) and restrict user with printing ebook, screenshot and other restrictions you want to add. To display pdf in django you can read an article here https://www.csestack.org/render-open-pdf-file-django/