# Hello, How do I display a PDF but prevent it from downloading?

Tags: next.js, react-pdf

when i was using nextjs and react-pdf but i faild to prevent medium user to download it because his able to go to the google tools inn the goole chrome and find the link of pdf inside network of goole dev tools
This is my pdfviewer.tsx page :

```
"use client"
import { useEffect } from 'react';
import {Document, Page, pdfjs} from 'react-pdf';

interface PdfViewerProps{
    pdfUrl:string;
}
const  PDFpage:React.FC<PdfViewerProps> =({pdfUrl})=>{
    useEffect(() => {
        pdfjs.GlobalWorkerOptions.workerSrc = `//unpkg.com/pdfjs-dist@${pdfjs.version}/build/pdf.worker.min.js`;
      }, []);
      return (
        <Document
        file={pdfUrl}
        >
            <Page pageNumber={1}/>
            <Page pageNumber={2}/>

        </Document>
      )
}
export default PDFpage
```

Comment: You misunderstand how the web works. If someone wants to show me a PDF then _by golly_ I'm going to download it, and you can't stop me. What are you afraid of, anyway?

Comment: Check this out: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4930914/prevent-pdf-file-from-downloading-and-printing - specifically "That is not possible. Reading is downloading.".

Answer (score -2):

The World Wide Web is "MIME (email) on steroids". You want people to read your wares, so you place it PO Boxes with IP monetized (advertized) by Google addresses. Then if they wish they visit the PO Box and "dis-position" the data to home for reading at leisure, especially when the web is jittery.

All files (HTML PDF Etc.) are binary bytes and have to be Hyper**TEXT**TransPorted:// from server to user. I.e. SENT via Get/Fetch.

Thus from the starting editable binary, via editable text, to browsing editor to edit onto screen as pixels or audio or used for annotation, a PDF is always in flux.

Every PDF is constantly being edited. That is what computers data is designed to do.

So can you personally use a PDF without "download"? Yes only if you don't publish by never offering a HTTP link.

Can you stop it being edited? Only by not allowing it to be opened except by yourself, as editor.

Comment: thank you very much for the good explanation and i want to shear with you my idea about stop the file bieng edited  can i do this using the pdf reader it self or use the platform that i used to upload the file which is the name is uploadthing and try the premium version . Or use dropbox as a file storage outside our databse and lod it from dropbox .....

Comment: ..... i 'm really stuck on this problem because some people tell me that is no way to prevent the pdf file from downloading when i try to show it , but whene i see the dropbox  paltform which load the file and make it availebel to read only and dont make it  donwloding ??