# Safe PDF view in ASP.NET MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, pdf

I have a PDF file and I want to allow users to view it online, but I want to prevent this document from being downloaded. Does know any solution to achieve that ?

Comment: see these http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4930914/prevent-pdf-file-from-downloading-and-printing, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4043801/how-to-prevent-pdf-document-from-being-download-to-users-pc

Answer (score 2):

This is fundamentally impossible.
The only way to view a PDF is to download it to a temp folder.  (the browser does this automatically)

On a deeper level (for any type of document), it is fundamentally impossible for you to tell what is sending an HTTP request.

Answer (score 0):

You could convert those PDFs to an ePaper solution.

[This is one option](http://www.epaperflip.com/)... but there are lots.

Comment: This answers the wording of the question... but the end user still has the "ePaper" file. It is trivially more complex to use it, but still...

Comment: @AndrewBarber, yep... it is more an alternative that a solution :)