# cakephp view PDF but not download

Tags: cakephp, pdf

I am displaying a PDF file from my webroot folder using the following code:

```
$this->viewClass = 'Media';   
$ext = pathinfo($file,PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
$params = array(
            'name'      => 'File',
            'download'  => false,
            'extension' => 'pdf',
            'path'      => 'webroot/'.$file
        );
$this->set($params);
```

the file opens up in the brower(Chrome) but the save option appears with it too. Is there a way i can display the PDF, but the user is not able to download this file?

Comment: You should always mention the exact cakephp version you are using. If you are using Cake2.x you should *not* use the deprecated view class. Use the response object instead. And no, each file that is displayed can always also be downloaded. This is not a CakePHP specific question then as this behavior is "basic law" regarding browsers. If you don't want sth to be downloaded, don't display it or cloak it using proprietary software like flash.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to Prevent PDF Document from Being download to users PC?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4043801/how-to-prevent-pdf-document-from-being-download-to-users-pc)

Answer (score 0):

Simply nope. Because once the file is viewed in the browser it is downloaded and saved temporarily somewhere in the user's machine. May be you can implement your own control to view the PDF but disable saving it, using flash or java script.