# Control the viewing of pdfs

Tags: google-chrome, pdf, client-side

I have some pdfs that should be viewable but not downloadable. Currently the pdfs are viewed and displayed in different browsers differently through various browser plugins that all permit pdf downloads. Is there a way to restrict these downloads if not in all plugins then just the google chrome pdf viewer specifically. Or is there a simple cross browser solution for viewing pdfs but not allowing them to be downloadable

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to Prevent PDF Document from Being download to users PC?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4043801/how-to-prevent-pdf-document-from-being-download-to-users-pc)

Answer (score 0):

By the time the PDF gets to the browser plugin, it's already been downloaded.

If you only want one page at a time, you'll need to implement a server-side mechanism to handle that.  Like Amazon's "Peek Inside" feature